# realm between query for two dates not working

Tags: android, realm

**realm between query for two dates not working**

> i have inserted data in realm like below

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    Diary diary = new Diary(Globals.getUniqueID(), new Date(), Globals.getDDMM(new Date()), 0, "1");

    realm.insertOrUpdate(diary);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

> i m fetching data like below

```
Date from = getPreviousSunDay().getTime();
Date to = getNextSaturDay().getTime();

RealmResults<Diary> results = realm.where(Diary.class).equalTo(Constant.GOAL_ID,
        model.getId()).greaterThanOrEqualTo(Constant.diary_date, from).lessThanOrEqualTo(Constant.diary_date, to).between(Constant.diary_date, from, to).sort(Constant.diary_date, Sort.DESCENDING).findAll();

private Calendar getNextSaturDay() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return cal;
}

private Calendar getPreviousSunDay() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1));
    return cal;
    // Log.e("DAY", cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "");
}
```

> above query returning 0 result but when change the query like below it return data

```
RealmResults<Diary> results = realm.where(Diary.class).equalTo(Constant.GOAL_ID, model.getId()).findAll();
```

**model class**

```
ublic class Diary extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private Date diary_date;
    private String name;
    private int state;// 0=white,1=yellow 2== green
    private String goal_id;


    public Diary() {
    }

    public Diary(Date diary_date) {
        this.diary_date = diary_date;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Diary)) return false;
        Diary diary = (Diary) o;

        /*DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return DATE_FORMAT.format(getDate()).compareTo(DATE_FORMAT.format(diary.getDate())) == 0;*/
         return getDate().equals(diary.getDate());
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getDate());
    }

    public Diary(String id, Date diary_date, String name, int state, String goal_id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.diary_date = diary_date;
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        this.goal_id = goal_id;
    }

    public String getGoal_id() {
        return goal_id;
    }

    public void setGoal_id(String goal_id) {
        this.goal_id = goal_id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return diary_date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.diary_date = date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

**Note:can anyone here please guide me what i m doing wrong here or give some link where i can find some date related crud operations. help really will be appreciated.**

Comment: have you tried `between(String fieldName, Date from, Date to)`? It's in the docs at https://realm.io/docs/java/5.8.0/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html

Comment: @AhmadSattout i have tried this but not working